# PHP function running on every refresh

Tags: php, mysql, refresh, records

Hi i have a function which adds a record to a database. After I have initially clicked submit if I refresh the page it will repeat the function again and again.

The code I am using to call the function is as follows.

```
if(isset($_POST["submitTask"])){
    insertTask();
};
```

I am new to mySQL and PHP as I used to use ASP and SQl but I cannot find a solution for php, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Change the `isset()` to `!empty()` does that do the trick for you?

Comment: After posting the form, redirect to the same page. This will clear all form submissions.

Comment: @Pupil do you want to put this as answer so i can mark it off?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After submitting the form:

```
if(isset($_POST["submitTask"])){
  insertTask();
  header("Location:your_form_page.php");
}
```

This redirection will clear all form submissions as page is redirecting, no form will be submitted.